# Promoting QWidget in Qt creator, problems with constructor

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwidget

I subclassed `QGraphicsView`:

```
class CustomGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    CustomGraphicsView(QWidget *parent = 0);
...
}
```

The constructor in the .cpp file is then implemented like this:

```
CustomGraphicsView::CustomGraphicsView(QWidget * parent):
    QGraphicsView(parent)
{
}
```

Now I promoted a QGraphicsView Widget via a Qt creator to CustomGraphicsView. But when I want to connect to the promoted widget in the constructor of my ImageWindow class;

```
ImageWindow::ImageWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ImageWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    CustomGraphicsView * view = ui->graphicsView();

}
```

I get the error message:

```
term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.
```

I specified a default value for the constructor namely QWidget *parent = 0, and in `ui_image_window.h` an argument is set:

```
graphicsView = new CustomGraphicsView(ImageWindow);
```

So what could cause this error then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `graphicsView` is a member rather than a method, so you do not need the parentheses. Just access it like `view = ui->graphicsView`. This is the same for all Qt widgets in your generated UI class - they are just members, not methods.